# Mapping of React Native components in iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, uiview, touchableopacity

We're trying to do automated testing of React Native application. For that, we want to figure out which React Native component maps to what iOS components. So far I can see that:

- `Image` (React) maps to `RCTImageView`/`UIImageView` (iOS)
- `ScrollView` (React) maps to `RCTCustomScrollView`/`UIScrollView` (iOS)

What about `TouchableOpacity` and `View`? How is that rendered on iOS? Where can I find a *full list* of these mappings?

Comment: Read this article : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/communication-ios

Comment: @ShamGir thanks. I've read it before. It's a bit too generic - I just don't see how it helps me to answer my specific question: what class is used to represent TouchableOpacity in iOS?